# Querying a User Profile model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm having trouble with this query.

**Users application**

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_story = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
           return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

*To avoid confusion, the 'current_story' will eventually be a foreign key for the Books.story model (excluded here) once I learn how to do use a foreign key across apps.*

**Books application**

models.py

```
class character(models.Model):

    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_story = models.ForeignKey(story, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from users.models import Profile
from .models import (character)

class listof_characters(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = character
    template_name = '/list_characters.html'
    context_object_name = 'characters'
    ordering = ['name']

    def get_queryset(self):
        ?
```

This is where i'm stuck. I need **character.fk_story = User.profile.current_story**.

I don't how to phrase this query, I've tried several different things based on other answers and I've tried User.current_story, User.userprofile.current_story as well.

I just need to filter the list of characters by *current* user's 'current_story' value.

Comment: I'm still learning so please ignore my ignorance, but if I write 'request.user.profile.current_story' where I've put the ? (i.e. the last line) - I get the an error that "Request" is an undefined term. If I change it to 'self.request.user.profile.current_story' I get an Attribute error "'Profile' object has no attribute 'current_story'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

        # or better use
        # profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.request.user)

        queryset = character.objects.filter(fk_story =profile.current_story)
        return queryset
```

In order for this to work, you also need to change your Profile model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_story = models.ForeignKey(story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
           return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Note here I am jusing foreignkey rather than integerfield.

Comment: Thank you, i've done as stated but i'm getting an error titled "'listof_characters' object has no attribute 'fk_user'.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried the new suggestion and am given the error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'current_story".

Comment: sorry. use```get``` rather than ```filter```

Comment: new error "column users_profile.current_story_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...sers_profile"."user_id", "users_profile"."image", "users_pro...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "users_profile.current_story". " - I tried adding a '.id' as well but it didn't change the error.

Comment: did you migrate after you change ```profile``` model as I suggested?

Comment: also may I ask why your foreignkey fileld has default ="1"? could you remove them?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't made migrations after changing the field to a FK, it's working now.

Comment: You will also probably want to set every story user creates as current and when he deletes the last set the new last one to be it :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
fk_story = Profile.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('current_story')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried placing this where I put the question mark in my question (below 'def get_queryset(self):') - but i'm given the NameError "name 'request' is not defined".

Comment: Put  request  after the LoginRequireMixin,ListView. Like 


class listof_characters(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView,request):. I hope this solves your Problem.

Comment: And you can also Use default = ' ' :- 
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Although another solution ended up working, I will try these to see if this works and I can get a better understanding of the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Do what Lars said but use `self.request.user` instead of `request.user`

**UPDATE**

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other urls
    path('characters/<int:pk>/', views.CharactersView.as_view(), name='characters'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class CharactersView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView)
    model = story
    template_name = '/list_characters.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        story = story.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']) # you need to pass a pk of the story you need the characters for in your url
        characters = character.objects.filter(fk_story=story)
        return characters
```

(here i replaced *ListView* with *DetailView* so we can query by the `story` model)

then in your template:

```
{% for character in characters %}
    {{ character.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

*P.S. Always start your Model names and ClassBasedViews with uppercase letters for better readability*

Comment: Thanks, after changing it to your suggestion, I'm getting the error "Cannot resolve keyword 'owner' into field. Choices are: ", it then lists out the Profile model fields.

Comment: I've updated my asnwer, this should get you the result you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the update, it gives me a KeyError and simpy says 'pk' (I think repeating what's the brackets after .kwargs). Is the fact the view is a listview making things more complicated?

Comment: I have updated the answer again, now it should work :)

Comment: It's bringing up the same error but the solution below worked. Thank you for all the help, i'll take your advice on board.